# Unable to create bootstrap-themed scaffold in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I'm trying to generate a bootstrap-themed scaffold via the following actions:

- Add `gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'` line to the end of the `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`
- Run `rails generate bootstrap:install static` as stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails)
- Place the DB account details (username and password) to the "default" section of `database.yml` file and run `rake db:create`
- Run `rails g scaffold Purchase company_name:text product_name:text contact_person:text email:text comment:text`
- Run rake `db:migrate`
- Run `rails g bootstrap:themed Purchases`

Every command returns 0, so I restarted a web-server and go to the `127.0.0.1:3000/purchases`, but it looks like it doesn't use twitter bootstrap at all:

[image]

**purchases/index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Listing purchases</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company name</th>
      <th>Product name</th>
      <th>Contact person</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Comment</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @purchases.each do |purchase| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= purchase.company_name %></td>
        <td><%= purchase.product_name %></td>
        <td><%= purchase.contact_person %></td>
        <td><%= purchase.email %></td>
        <td><%= purchase.comment %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', purchase %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_purchase_path(purchase) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', purchase, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Purchase', new_purchase_path %>
```

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

I'm using Ruby on Rails 4.1.4 btw.

Comment: Did you generate the layout for `application`?

Comment: @mccannf How can I do it? By running the command rails g bootstrap:layout [LAYOUT_NAME]?

Comment: @FrozenHeart  change this command to `rails g bootstrap:themed Purchases` to `rails g bootstrap:themed Purchase` as you need to apply theme to your model

Comment: @anusha It doesn't work too

Comment: Yes `rails g bootstrap:layout application` and confirm you want to overwrite the existing layout. **If** you want to use bootstrap throughout the app.

Comment: @mccannf Ok, I'll try it, but why do I need it?

Comment: @FrozenHeart change the gem like this and `gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'` and try generate bootstrap theme again `rails g bootstrap:themed Purchase`

Comment: @FrozenHeart. Hmm, actually you should not need it if you generated the theme for Bootstrap. Can you confirm that `app/assets/javascript/application.js` and `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` contain requires for bootstrap? Did the generate theme for Purchases overwrite all the `.erb` files? There is something wrong here. Did you add the `therubyracer` gem as well?

Comment: There should be no need to override the application layout. Focus on the table styles. (See my answer below.)

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

1. Make sure the `<table>` tag has the class(es) required by Bootstrap. For example: `<table class="table table-striped">`.
2. Also, the scaffold-generated styles in `app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.scss` might be interfering. Remove them and see what happens.

And as @anusha said in a comment, remember to [use the singular form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10035470/3345375) when you run the generator.  For example: `rails g bootstrap:themed Purchase`, not `Purchases`.

Comment: Deleting scaffolds.css worked for me. Thank you so much.